# Mysql union query, joining results with names

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT  COUNT(ID) AS RANK1 FROM `db_ranking` WHERE `sid`=2 AND `rank`=1
UNION
SELECT  COUNT(ID) AS RANK2  FROM `db_ranking` WHERE `sid`=2 AND `rank`=2
UNION
SELECT  COUNT(ID) AS RANK3  FROM `db_ranking` WHERE `sid`=2 AND `rank`=3
UNION
SELECT   COUNT(ID)  AS RANK4  FROM `db_ranking` WHERE `sid`=2 AND `rank`=4
UNION
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS RANK5 FROM `db_ranking` WHERE `sid`=2 AND `rank`=5
```

I want to present every SELECT result in a column..

So I want to have 5 columns, each column has got a count of ID..

so it should be like that

```
RANK1 RANK2 RANK3 RANK4 RANK5
  0     3     5     6     7
```

I am not getting it now..and I dont know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the below works fine ..

```
  select
    (SELECT  COUNT(ID) AS RANK1 FROM `db_ranking` WHERE `sid`=2 AND `rank`=1) as Rank1,
    (SELECT  COUNT(ID) AS RANK2  FROM `db_ranking` WHERE `sid`=2 AND `rank`=2) as rank2,
    (SELECT  COUNT(ID) AS RANK3  FROM `db_ranking` WHERE `sid`=2 AND `rank`=3) as rank3,
    (SELECT   COUNT(ID)  AS RANK4  FROM `db_ranking` WHERE `sid`=2 AND `rank`=4) as rank4,
    (SELECT COUNT(ID) AS RANK5 FROM `db_ranking` WHERE `sid`=2 AND `rank`=5) as rank5
    from dual
```

Comment: lol..nice solution, but it gives me no results when it should

Comment: can you explain me the no solution part ? please !

Comment: it is when phpmyadmin,,executes the query and shows nothing..no message.. no results no nothing..the query stays where it was , and the page is just refreshed

Comment: sorry buddy am not aware of phpmyadmin , but its working in mysql console as well as sqlserver . may be you can add PHP in your tag..

Comment: This is very ineffecient that queries the same table five times. See the method I posted. It is simple and more effecient

Answer (score 0):

The most effecient method would be

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN `rank`=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Rank1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `rank`=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Rank2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `rank`=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Rank3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `rank`=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Rank4,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `rank`=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Rank5
FROM
    `db_ranking`
WHERE
    `sid`=2
```